# How do they measure the rotational speed of cricket balls?

Tags: everyday-life, radar

[The 2013 Ashes series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2013_Ashes_series) (a cricket thing between England and Australia) are underway as of today and it seems they have a new (to me) gimmick. It appears that they are now able to measure almost instantaneously (within a few seconds) the rotational speed of balls bowled by spin bowlers.

[image]

On the (golf) driving range, I was able to get similar readings, but they were from a machine only a few feet away from the tee. I don't quite understand that either, but it seems at least easier. Although there, they were even able to determine the rotational axis as well.

[image]

But in cricket they also have a rotational axis along the direction of the ball, which is even more difficult to measure (unless they have a third radar somewhere perpendicular-*ish* to the pitch).

*I think* I now see that they placed very small black boxes between two of the stumps on either end of the pitch. I guess that must be the first two radars. (One of which will be useless because the batsman is standing in front of it.)

[image]

So, essentially: How do they do it? And, how accurate can it be, given that the reflection of the "sides" of the ball may be poor? Or are they using (visible-light) camera images, as suggested by the comments of udiboy and Deer Hunter below? (I'm fairly confident the golf system doesn't do that, but I don't *know*. Anyways, to make sure, the question is primarily about the cricket.)

---

*Added later.*

I found that they measure spin rates in baseball as well: http://sportsillustrated.cnn.com/2011/writers/tom_verducci/04/12/fastballs.trackman/index.html.

The http://trackman.dk site refers to these technologies and (patent/patent application) numbers:

> - Measuring spin rate of sports balls by radar using multiple harmonic
>     spectrum traces. (US2009/0075744, EP1698380,
>     DE602006009719.0, GB/EP/1698380, ZL200680006869.0, JP2008/538085A and
>     KR10/0947898)
> - Measuring spin axis orientation of sport balls from trajectory
>     measurements by radar. (US2009/0075744, DE602006015036.9,
>     GB/EP/1853362, ZL200680006869.0, JP2008/538085A and KR10/0947898)

Comment: maybe they snapshot successive images of the ball, and check how *thread* of the ball moves. That can give you a rough estimate of the rotational axis.

Comment: Is it [Hot Spot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Spot_(cricket)), or a recent update of [Hawk Eye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spot_Shot)? Regardless, optical stereo trackers can find rotation transforms for successive shots and estimate the angular velocity vector (no first-hand experience, though). In cricket, though, there's a lot of background noise...

Comment: Could the balls have gyros and emiters inside them?

Comment: Some of the trackers work in infrared light.

Comment: @ja72 ,the balls do not have any gyros or emitters inside. they are manufactured using very strict regulations. check this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cricket_ball

Comment: It's almost certainly what @udiboy says--take an image of the ball with a high-speed camera, then mark the motion of a marking on the ball between a few frames.

Comment: A spin ball essentially changes direction and speed after its first hit on the pitch. I am writing this as a comment since I am not sure. Now, the change in speed and direction after the spin would somehow be related to the rotational axis and rotational speed. I still have to check whether you do get solvable equations using this theory.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate: [Technology behind the 'rev counter' for spin bowlers?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/2966/technology-behind-the-rev-counter-for-spin-bowlers). At least as of October 2017, contains a similar lack of definitive answers.

Answer (score 1):

If the balls are kept clean, a high-speed camera coupled to a computer running an image recognition/analysis program ought to be adequate. As an example of the sorts of images you can get, see [this cricket match](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSAiSTkVMfs) At about 1:35 you can see slow motion with a long lens. The stripe on the ball is very visible.

As a starting point, an upper limit of 3000 rpm (per your first image) gives 50 rps. At normal (at least, as normal as cricket-playing countries get) PAL video rates of 50 fps that's a maximum of 1 revolution per frame, so high speed should easily be able to resolve the rotation. And, of course, there's no guarantee that the 4 figures presented in the image are precise. I suspect the last two significant digits are bogus.

Designing such a system, I expect, would be quite challenging, but the problem would be in designating the period and exact area of interest, and doing it in a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20000112958_2000155072.pdf) is a link.

What you'll see is a lot of detail on experiments which relate the trajectory of the ball with initial conditions. The high-speed camera thing is a possible solution, but doesn't appeal to me in a scientific manner, because it's hard to imagine how would you actually implement high-speed cameras or gyros or emitters inside in an Ashes game.

[image: an example of graphs I said]

I am proposing an alternate solution. Just as in the link I gave above, it is possible and has of course been done, to get an idea of trajectories followed by the ball under different conditions. Now, it is a very easy business for a machine learning algorithm to find the best match for the initial conditions of the ball given a trajectory. Some other initial conditions such as meteorological details and type of pitch can be entered manually.

I have no idea if this is how they do it. It's just the way I would do it. And it doesn't have to be too accurate. The audience is very happy just for the fact that they show the spin.

Comment: Looking at the patents in the question, this seems to be how some of the claims in the first patent works, though there's no mention of machine learning.